# Incorrect translation from logic address to machine address, GDT

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, memory-address

I'm using bochs to debug the JOS of MIT. I'm confused at the address of the bochs's output:

```
(0) [0x0010002e] 0008:0xf010002e (unk. ctxt): mov ebp, 0x00000000       ; bd00000000
```

I'm trying to figure out how `0008:0xf010002e` is transfered to `[0x0010002e]`.

Based on the transfermation from logic addr. to linear address, I think I should use the base address from the GDT's 8th entry to plus the offset `0xf010002e`.

However, I got the GDT's content as follows:

```
<bochs:6> x /16wx 0x0010f000
[bochs]:
0x0010f000 <bogus+       0>:    0x00000000  0x00000000  0x0000ffff  0x10cf9a00
0x0010f010 <bogus+      16>:    0x0000ffff  0x10cf9300  0xf0000017  0x00000010
0x0010f020 <bogus+      32>:    0x32311b00  0x36353433  0x30393837  0x09083d2d
0x0010f030 <bogus+      48>:    0x72657771  0x69757974  0x5d5b706f  0x7361000a
```

The 8th entry is:

```
0x69757974  0x5d5b706f
```

Based on the entry's format at [Fig 5-3](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/s05_01.htm#fig5-4), the base address is: `0x730a8d5b`.  However, 0x730a8d5b + 0xf010002e  is not 0x0010002e!

Can anyone help me point out where I'm wrong?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0008` means first segment, not 8th.
Thus, `0x0000ffff  0x10cf9a00` means segment base = 0x10000000, so `0008:0xf010002e` overlaps to 0x0010002e.

**Edit**: (answering the comment)

The lowest bits 0 and 1 of segment selector is used as privilege level (ring) selector, bit 2 - selects between GDT and LDT, all the other bits are used as offset to relevant descriptors table. Thus, `0x0008` to `0x000b` means `0x0008` offset in GDT with privilege levels 0..3

Pointer for the explanation: [Intel Software Developer Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), vol.3, ch.3

Comment: Hi @qwm, why 0008 means first segment? could you please explain a little or give me a pointer for the explanation? Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe the 0008 means 8B offset? Then it refers to the first entry of the GDT?